# Rails 4 routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a question routing for an app I am making in Ruby/Rails. I have two different models, a user, and an admin. First I set up the user and it worked well independently. The user has "sign_in", "signed_out", "account_settings", "login" methods etc.

Then I created an admin model. Which is pretty similar to a user, except it is going to have abilities to delete/ban user models. The problem is, I would like to use a similar routing method, except with the prefix "/admin/". I was looking into scopes, and namespaces, however I just could not get everything to route correctly. This is what my `config/routes.rb` file looks like a the moment:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'home#index'

  scope 'admin' do
    get "sign_in" => "admin#sign_in"
    post "sign_in" => "admin#login"
    get "signed_out" => "admin#signed_out"
  end

  get "sign_in" => "authentication#sign_in"
  post "sign_in" => "authentication#login"

  get "signed_out" => "authentication#signed_out"
  get "new_user" => "authentication#new_user"
  put "new_user" => "authentication#register"

  get "account_settings" => "authentication#account_settings"
  put "account_settings" => "authentication#set_account_info"

  get "forgot_password" => "authentication#forgot_password"
  put "forgot_password" => "authentication#send_password_reset_instructions"

  get "password_reset" => "authentication#password_reset"
  put "password_reset" => "authentication#new_password"
end
```

Is there something that I am doing wrong? I want the routes for admin to be `localhost:3000/admin/sign_in` and `localhost:3000/admin/signed_out` and the routes for users to be `localhost:3000/sign_in` and `localhost:3000/signed_out`

Thanks

Addition: output of `rake routes` is as follows

```
$ rake routes
          Prefix Verb URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
            root GET  /                                 home#index
         sign_in GET  /admin/sign_in(.:format)          admin#sign_in
                 POST /admin/sign_in(.:format)          admin#login
      signed_out GET  /admin/signed_out(.:format)       admin#signed_out
account_settings GET  /admin/account_settings(.:format) admin#account_settings
                 GET  /sign_in(.:format)                authentication#sign_in
                 POST /sign_in(.:format)                authentication#login
                 GET  /signed_out(.:format)             authentication#signed_out
        new_user GET  /new_user(.:format)               authentication#new_user
                 PUT  /new_user(.:format)               authentication#register
                 GET  /account_settings(.:format)       authentication#account_settings
                 PUT  /account_settings(.:format)       authentication#set_account_info
 forgot_password GET  /forgot_password(.:format)        authentication#forgot_password
                 PUT  /forgot_password(.:format)        authentication#send_password_reset_instructions
  password_reset GET  /password_reset(.:format)         authentication#password_reset
                 PUT  /password_reset(.:format)         authentication#new_password
```

How can i create custom helper paths so that I don't need to manually type them out in each form/link?

Edit:

New routes info file is as follows

```
root_path   GET /   home#index
admin_sign_in_path  GET /admin/sign_in(.:format)    admin/admin#sign_in
POST    /admin/sign_in(.:format)    admin/admin#login
admin_signed_out_path   GET /admin/signed_out(.:format) admin/admin#signed_out
admin_account_settings_path GET /admin/account_settings(.:format)   admin/admin#account_settings
sign_in_path    GET /sign_in(.:format)  authentication#sign_in
POST    /sign_in(.:format)  authentication#login
signed_out_path GET /signed_out(.:format)   authentication#signed_out
new_user_path   GET /new_user(.:format) authentication#new_user
PUT /new_user(.:format) authentication#register
account_settings_path   GET /account_settings(.:format) authentication#account_settings
PUT /account_settings(.:format) authentication#set_account_info
forgot_password_path    GET /forgot_password(.:format)  authentication#forgot_password
PUT /forgot_password(.:format)  authentication#send_password_reset_instructions
password_reset_path GET /password_reset(.:format)   authentication#password_reset
PUT /password_reset(.:format)   authentication#new_password
```

Comment: Right now it is sending even the `localhost:3000/sign_in` to the admin sign in page

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried changing it to `scope '/admin'`?

Comment: Use "$ rake routes"  when designing your routes

Comment: Or visit: localhost:3000/rails/info/routes

Comment: Checked it out, and it looks like everything is being routed correctly I just need to look into my path helpers that are the links of form submittals and nav bar links. I'm seeing in /info/routes where those paths are pointing so I just need to look into how to specify those path helpers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The original method was not working because it was simply re-binding "sign_in_path" to the admin controller and then there was no helper path to the authentication controller, even though the routes were set up correctly, the helper in the form and in the links pointer to the "incorrect things".

To fix, I visited `localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` and noticed that these helpers were as follows:

```
$ rake routes
          Prefix Verb URI Pattern                       Controller#Action
            root GET  /                                 home#index
         sign_in GET  /admin/sign_in(.:format)          admin#sign_in
                 POST /admin/sign_in(.:format)          admin#login
      signed_out GET  /admin/signed_out(.:format)       admin#signed_out
account_settings GET  /admin/account_settings(.:format) admin#account_settings
                 GET  /sign_in(.:format)                authentication#sign_in
                 POST /sign_in(.:format)                authentication#login
                 GET  /signed_out(.:format)             authentication#signed_out
        new_user GET  /new_user(.:format)               authentication#new_user
                 PUT  /new_user(.:format)               authentication#register
                 GET  /account_settings(.:format)       authentication#account_settings
                 PUT  /account_settings(.:format)       authentication#set_account_info
 forgot_password GET  /forgot_password(.:format)        authentication#forgot_password
                 PUT  /forgot_password(.:format)        authentication#send_password_reset_instructions
  password_reset GET  /password_reset(.:format)         authentication#password_reset
                 PUT  /password_reset(.:format)         authentication#new_password
```

I fixed my `config/routes.rb` file to contain the following:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'home#index'

  namespace :admin, :module => false do
    get "sign_in" => "admin#sign_in"
    post "sign_in" => "admin#login"
    get "signed_out" => "admin#signed_out"
    get "account_settings" => "admin#account_settings"
    put "account_settings" => "admin#set_account_info"
    get "users" => "admin#users"
    delete "user/:id" => "admin#delete_user", :as =>"user"
  end

  get "sign_in" => "authentication#sign_in"
  post "sign_in" => "authentication#login"

  get "signed_out" => "authentication#signed_out"
  get "new_user" => "authentication#new_user"
  put "new_user" => "authentication#register"

  get "account_settings" => "authentication#account_settings"
  put "account_settings" => "authentication#set_account_info"

  get "forgot_password" => "authentication#forgot_password"
  put "forgot_password" => "authentication#send_password_reset_instructions"

  get "password_reset" => "authentication#password_reset"
  put "password_reset" => "authentication#new_password"
end
```

Which then made my helper paths look more like the following:

```
root_path   GET /   home#index
admin_sign_in_path  GET /admin/sign_in(.:format)    admin#sign_in
POST    /admin/sign_in(.:format)    admin#login
admin_signed_out_path   GET /admin/signed_out(.:format) admin#signed_out
admin_account_settings_path GET /admin/account_settings(.:format)   admin#account_settings
PUT /admin/account_settings(.:format)   admin#set_account_info
admin_users_path    GET /admin/users(.:format)  admin#users
admin_user_path DELETE  /admin/user/:id(.:format)   admin#delete_user
sign_in_path    GET /sign_in(.:format)  authentication#sign_in
POST    /sign_in(.:format)  authentication#login
signed_out_path GET /signed_out(.:format)   authentication#signed_out
new_user_path   GET /new_user(.:format) authentication#new_user
PUT /new_user(.:format) authentication#register
account_settings_path   GET /account_settings(.:format) authentication#account_settings
PUT /account_settings(.:format) authentication#set_account_info
forgot_password_path    GET /forgot_password(.:format)  authentication#forgot_password
PUT /forgot_password(.:format)  authentication#send_password_reset_instructions
password_reset_path GET /password_reset(.:format)   authentication#password_reset
PUT /password_reset(.:format)   authentication#new_password
```

and then I just had to adjust my paths in the forms and nav bar links accordingly. Thanks all!